# connecting database through hibernate after recovery of database

Tags: hibernate, connection-pooling

Please suggest whether hibernate has some mechanism to detect the recovery of rdbms and reconnect to it automatically if the database gets down and recovers?

Comment: What DB are you talking about?

Comment: Why hibernate needs do it?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does not. But underlying connection pools like C3P0 do. For C3P0 you need to specify connection-test query and test-period. Details here: [C3P0 configuration](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing)